# SSL_do_handshake() failed en NGINX con WordPress

Tags: wordpress, nginx, certificado-ssl

Revisando el log de errores en NGINX con WordPress me encuentro el siguiente registro:

SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14201044:SSL routines:tls_choose_sigalg:internal
error) while SSL handshaking

El sitio aveces se cae y genera un error 504 Gateway Timeout,
¿este registro en log puede ser el causante del error 504?

Comment: Has probado con googlear el error, lo acabo de hacer y hay mucha información sobre ello, conforme a que se caiga el servidor, me he topado con un 504 antes, caídas de servidor de la nada y generalmente suele pasar por falta de memoria, intenta aumentar la memoria y controlar mejor los recursos para intentar verificar el porque el servidor se rompe, dudo que sea por el problema de ssl.

Answer (score -1):

Podría ser un problema con los certificados o la llave privada. Deberías probar si el sitio de funciona solo con http.

Comment: Esto es mas un comentario que una respuesta.